# Разрезать изображение большого разрешения на куски с заданными размерами Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

У меня возникла необходимость программно разрезать картинку очень большого разрешения на отдельные квадраты заданного размера.

Программа выполняет разрез картинки в два этапа - сначала она разрезает изображение по y-координате на полоски заданной высоты, а после - каждую такую полоску по заданной ширине. На продольные полосы программа изображение режет почти без проблем. Единственное, она создаёт лишние *.jpg* файлы. Но при попытке порезать эту новую горизонтальную полосу поперёк, она кромсает её на не квадраты по 256 пикселей, а на вертикальные полосы шириной в 1 пиксель

Вот код:

```py
import numpy as nm 
import cv2 as cv 
import os 

class PictureCutter:
    def __init__(self, picture, cut_x, cut_y):
        self.graph_object = cv.imread(picture)
        self.cut_area = {
            'x' : cut_x,
            'y' : cut_y
        }


    def calc_picture_parameters(self, picture = None):
        picture = cv.imread(picture)

        self.picture_hight = picture.shape[0]
        self.picture_width = picture.shape[1]

        self.cut_ystep = self.picture_hight // self.cut_area['y'] 
        self.cut_xstep = self.picture_width // self.cut_area['x']


    def cut_picture_y(self):
        y = 0

        for line in range(self.cut_ystep):
            address = 'image{}.jpg'.format(line)

            cv.imwrite(address, self.graph_object[y:y+self.cut_area['y']])
            y += self.cut_area['y']

    def load_pict(self, address):
        for picture in os.listdir(address):
            yield picture

    def cut_picture_x(self, dir):

        for picture in self.load_pict(dir):
            obj = cv.imread(dir +'/'+ picture)
            self.calc_picture_parameters(picture = str(dir) + '/' + str(picture))
            x = 0
            for line in range(self.cut_xstep):
                address = 'Ximage{0}.jpg'.format(line)

                cv.imwrite(address, obj[obj.shape[0]-1,x:x+self.cut_area['x']])
                x += self.cut_area['x']
```

Честно говоря, я не особо представляю, почему именно происходит так, как происходит. Вероятно, я ошибся в методе _calc_picture_parameters_, но меня сильно сбивает с толку тот факт, что методы _cut_picture_y_ и _cut_picture_x_ по своему функционалу крайне схожи, но **один работает почти так, как должен, а второй - не пойми как**.

Как и что я должен исправить в этом коде, что бы он работал так, как должен?